# Mongoid: Comments on MongoDB and User on MySQL? How to make it work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I want to create an app that uses both MongoDB and MySQL. Specifically, I want mongodb to store all the users' comments while MySQL will store the User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  belongs_to :user
end
```

well, everything looks good except when I go to the rails console and run this.

```
k = Comment.new
k.user = User.first
```

I got

> NoMethodError:   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
>   WHERE `users`.`_id` = 1 Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users._id' in
>   'where clause': SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`_id` = 1
>   undefined method `from_map_or_db' for

It looks like that the `:=` method is looking for the `_id` of the model instea of the `id`? Is there a workaround to get this working automatically or do I need to create my own `=` method? 
Has anyone tried the same configuration before? If so, what are the steps to get all these to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not gonna work like you want it to. Your `belongs_to :user` in `Comment` is telling Mongoid to make this association in MongoDB; in order to make ActiveRecord associations, your class must inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` or include `ActiveRecord::Model`--and you can't do both!

Probably the best way to do this--and I don't know how difficult it would be--is to write your own methods to associate the `Users` and `Comments` together.

Answer (score 2):

You might try an association table:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :thoughts, :foreign_key => "user_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :through => :thoughts, :source => :user
end

class Thought < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :comment, :class_name => "Comment"
end

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  has_many :thoughts, :foreign_key => "_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :user, :through => :thoughts, :source => :comment
end
```

I don't have any way of testing this at the moment but, it may work.  Your thought model will need user_id and _id columns.